# What the best way to create a namespace in javascript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

In Internet very common approach to use namespace in javascript for the product as "window.com.company.product".

And I trying to use this approach. But I see very painful for customer to use this kind of API for the products:

```
window.com = window.com || {};
window.com.company = window.com.company || {};
window.com.company.product = window.com.company.product || [];
productAPI = window.com.company.product;
productAPI.push({});
```

Instead I want to propose different approach:

```
window['com.company.product'] = window['com.company.product'] || [];
productAPI = window.com.company.product;
productAPI.push({});
```

I think it's much easier to use, but all benefits are the same.
What do you think? What disadvantages do you see in the second approach?

Product (usage example):

```
(function(){
    window.com = window.com || {};
    window.com.company = window.com.company || {};
    window.com.company.product = window.com.company.product || [];

    var data = copy(window.com.company.product);
    ...

    window.com.company.product.push = function() {
    ...
    }
}());
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can make a function that resolves the path for you filling with empty objects if necessary.

Comment: Yes, it will be available in my product, but not at the moment of product configuration.

Comment: How is your product defined? I presume you are using an IIFE, can you post sime code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using immediate function. Example added to the main post.